# Does the modulus of a linear operator change continuously with the operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, perturbation-theory

Let $X,Y$ be real Banach spaces, and let $B(X,Y)$ be the space of bounded linear operators.

Given $T \in B(X,Y)$ the *modulus* of $T$ is defined to be

$$
\gamma(T):=\inf \{ \,\|Tx\| \, \, | \, \, d(x,\ker T)=1 \}.
$$
It is known that if the image of $T$ is closed in $Y$, then $\gamma(T)>0$.

**Suppose that:**

1. $T_n \in B(X,Y)$ is a sequence of operators with closed images, and that $T_n \to T$ in the operator norm.
2. $T$ has a closed image.
3. $\dim \ker T_n=\dim \ker T< \infty$. (All the kernels are finite-dimensional and of the same dimension).

> Is it true that $\gamma(T_n) \ge c $ for some $ c >0$ independent of $n$?

If the modulus was a continuous map $B(X,Y) \to \mathbb{R}$, then we had $\gamma(T_n) \to \gamma(T)>0$. So the answer would be positive. However, I am not sure the modulus is continuous. Nonetheless, I am interested in the weaker result - must the modulus of a convergent sequence be bounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, observe that in order to prove this statement, it suffices to find a subsequence of $(T_n)$ on which $\gamma(T_n)$ is bounded away from $0$.  If the statement were false, then we could find a subsequence of $(T_n)$ on which $\gamma(T_n)\to 0$, and then applying our argument starting with that subsequence, we would reach a contradiction.

Now let us prove a lemma.

> **Lemma**: Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $X$ such that $T_nx_n\to 0$.  Then some subsequence of $(x_n)$ converges to an element of $\ker T$.
>
> *Proof*: Since $T_n\to T$ uniformly on bounded sets, $Tx_n\to 0$.  Since $\gamma(T)>0$, this implies that $d(x_n,\ker T)\to 0$.  We can thus choose $y_n\in\ker T$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)\to 0$.  Since $(x_n)$ is bounded, so is $(y_n)$.  Since $\ker T$ is finite-dimensional, some subsequence of $(y_n)$ converges to some $y\in \ker T$.  The corresponding subsequence of $(x_n)$ then also converges to $y$.

Now, let $r=\dim \ker T$.  For each $n$, choose a basis $x^1_n,\dots,x^r_n$ of $\ker T_n$ which is "almost orthonormal" in the sense that for each $i$, $x^i_n$ is a unit vector and $d(x^i_n,\operatorname{span}(x^1_n,\dots,x^{i-1}_n))\geq 1/2$.  By the lemma, we may pass to a subsequence and assume that for each $i$, $(x^i_n)$ converges to some $x^i\in\ker T$.  These $x^i$ will also be almost orthonormal, and so in particular will be linearly independent and thus a basis of $\ker T$.

Now suppose that $\gamma(T_n)\to 0$.  This means that we can choose $y_n\in X$ such that $d(y_n,\ker T_n)=1$ for each $n$ but $T_ny_n\to 0$.  Modifying $y_n$ by an element of $\ker T_n$, we may assume that $(y_n)$ is bounded.  By the lemma, we may pass to a subsequence and assume that $(y_n)$ converges to some $y\in\ker T$.  Writing $y$ as a linear combination of $x^1,\dots,x^r$, we see that for large $n$, $y_n$ is close to the corresponding linear combination of $x^1_n,\dots,x^r_n$.  This contradicts the assumption that $d(y_n,\ker T_n)=1$.

Thus $\gamma(T_n)$ does not converge to $0$.  This means we can pass to a subsequence and conclude that $\gamma(T_n)$ is bounded away from $0$, as desired.

Comment: Wow! this is a great answer. One question though: Why can you always choose an "almost orthonormal" basis for a finite-dimensional normed space? Is it because all the norms are equivalent? Thanks.

Comment: Just choose the basis vectors one by one.  Having chosen $x^1_n,\dots,x^{i-1}_n$, let $y$ be some vector of distance $1$ from their span.  Modifying $y$ by an element of the span, you can assume that $y$ is almost a unit vector.  Rescaling it to be a unit vector, you get a unit vector whose distance from the span is close to $1$, which you can take to be $x^i_n$.

Comment: The purpose of this "almost orthonormal" business is just to guarantee that the limit $x^1,\dots,x^r$ is still linearly independent.  In other words, we're forcing our bases for $\ker T_n$ to not just be linearly independent, but far away from being linearly dependent in a quantitative way that is preserved by taking limits.

Comment: Thanks, this is very nice! (I thought using equivalence of norms to an inner product induced norm, so you can choose every element basis far away from all the other, not only its predecessors). You have sort of proved a "continuity property" of the kernels, which is what I was really after. (In some sense, the continuity of the modulus and the "continuity of the kernel" are two different sides of the same picture). Your proof does not tell us immediately whether or not the modulus is indeed continuous... but I guess this will have to wait to a different time... Thanks again for this answer.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing something like comparing to an inner product norm, but an issue with that seems to be that each $\ker T_n$ has a _different_ norm.  Each one of those norms is equivalent to some inner product norm, but what if the constants of equivalence that you need to use are unbounded?  Maybe there is a way to make it work, but that issue dissuaded me from trying it.

Comment: A remark: If $X$ is reflexive, all finite-dimension assumptions can be removed. The sequences $x_n, y_n$ have weak convergent subsequences and $\ker T$ is a weakly closed set. There is also no need to do the (clever) almost-orthogonality step.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: The finite (and equal) dimension assumptions are crucial for more than just getting convergent subsequences.  They are needed to choose the bases $\{x^i_n\}$ and then conclude that the limit $\{x^i\}$ is a basis of $\ker T$.  Without the assumption that the kernels all have the same dimension, it is easy to get counterexamples even when $X$ itself is finite-dimensional.

Comment: (For instance, let $T_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of nonzero scalars which converge to $0$.)

Comment: The key point is that we need $\{x^i\}$ to span $\ker T$, and the only way we know that is by seeing that they are a linearly independent set of the right size.  This only works if $\ker T$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Oh right, I got excited, sorry about that. I am a bit confused by the counterexample (what is $\gamma(0)$? and isn't $\dim \ker T_n = 0 < \dim \ker 0 = 1$?), but you convinced me about the need of a choice of bases.

Comment: I would say $\gamma(0)=\infty$, since you're taking the infimum of the empty set.  The point of the example is that it shows how the assumption $\dim\ker T_n=\dim\ker T$ is necessary (and could similarly break down if they had the same dimension but the dimension was infinite, since you could just take a direct sum with an infinite-dimensional space on which all the maps are $0$).

Comment: @EricWofsey I wanted to thank you again for this wonderful answer. I am going to use  it as a (very) small part in a paper I am writing. Of course, I would like to give you credit for it. If you have any specific requests or objections, please let me know. Thanks again.